# Using NOT operator to screen data using multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, operators

I have a homework question asking me to find "What employees are not assigned to any HP computers? "

I have tried the following method:

```
select empname from Employee where empnum in
(select empnum from PC where comp in
  (select comp from computer where MFRNAME NOT LIKE 'HP'))
```

However. I am still getting data from employee Douglas Dally who has two computers. One of which being an HP and the other not an HP. But I am suppose to find only the employees that do not use any HP computers at all. How can I go about screening out this result?

I have attached a link to my data below.

[image]

Comment: Since it is homework I just have some suggestions to get you onto the right track. Think about joining tables together rather than sub-queries. PC joins onto Employee and Computer joins onto .... Finally use the `where` condition.

Comment: And from a logic perspective, you are trying to find staff `where not exists` an HP computer assigned to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` if you want to get employees that don't use HP laptops as well.

```
select empname
from Employee em
where not exists (
  select 1
  from PC p 
  join comp c on c.comp = p.comp 
  where em.empnum = p.empnum  
  and c.MFRNAME like '%HP%'
)
```

This should give you the employees who don't use computers like HP and if HP is absolute string then you can mention as `c.MFRNAME = 'HP'`

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with the following result which I believe is almost exactly what you did there.   select empname from employee
where not exists (
                    select empnum
                    from PC 
                    inner join computer on pc.comp = computer.comp
                    where PC.empnum = employee.empnum
                    and computer.mfrname = 'HP' )
order by employee.empnum